Fundamental group of torus glued with Mobius strip
I have seen this question before, but I seem to get a wrong answer, and I have no idea why.
Let $\pi_1$ be the fundamental group of the space obtained from a torus $S^1 \times S^1$ and a Mobius strip $M$ by identifying the boundary of $M$ with $S^1 \times \{x\}$, where $x \in S^1$. Find $\pi_1$.
What I tried to do is to impose a CW structure on this space, and then use the fact that the fundamental group is generated by $1$-cells, and the relations are boundaries of $2$-cells. Here is my structure:

The logic is that we can take the vertex of $a$ and call in $x$, then the boundary of the Mobius band is being identified with $S^1$ that is represented by $a$.
The $\pi_1$ we get this way is: $\langle a,b,c | ab = ba, aca^{-1}c\rangle$, which seems to be wrong, the second relation should be $a^2 = c$, but I don't think it is equal to what I got. Where is my mistake?

Your picture does not match the object described by your words.
What your picture shows instead is the result of attaching the Möbius band with an attaching map that wraps the boundary of the Möbius band two times around the circle $S^1 \times \{x\}$.
If you want your attaching map to wrap the boundary of the Möbius band one time around the circle $S^1 \times \{x\}$, then in the torus rectangle you should first subdivide the $a$ edge into two edges $a_1 a_2$, adding a vertex at the midpoint of $a$. Then you should label your Möbius band rectangle as $a_1 c a_2^{-1} c$ (and then the $a_1$ side of your Möbius band rectangle would attach only to the first half of the $a$ side of your torus rectangle).
One side effect is that your CW complex will no longer have one vertex --- it will instead have two vertices --- so you'll have to choose the maximal tree to be one of the edges in the 1-skeleton that connects those two vertices (either $a_1$ or $a_2$), whose label gets ignored when writing the presentation.
